# Federated authentication and Delegated authentication in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, federated-identity

Anybody know the difference between Federated authentication and Delegated authentication in salesforce? Can you explain the flow of request in these two methods?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The main difference is the use of Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) on Federated Authentication.

> **Delegated Authentication** Use delegated authentication if you have mobile users in your organization, or if you want to enable
>   single-sign on for partner portals or Customer Portals. You must
>   request that this feature be enabled by salesforce.com. This recipe
>   explains delegated authentication in more detail.
>
> **Federated Authentication using SAML** Federated authentication uses SAML, an industry standard for secure integrations. Investing in SAML
>   with Salesforce.com can be leveraged with other products or services.
>   If you use SAML, you don't have to expose an internal server to the
>   Internet: the secure integration is done using the browser. In
>   addition, Salesforce.com never handles any passwords used by your
>   organization. For more information, see “Configuring SAML Settings for
>   Single Sign-On” in the Salesforce.com online help.

**Difference**

Delegated authentication has a few drawbacks with respect to federated authentication. First, **delegated authentication is inherently **less secure** than federated authentication**. Even if encrypted, delegated authentication still sends the username and password (possibly even your network password) over the internet to Force.com. Some companies have policies that preclude a third party for handling their network passwords. Second, **delegated authentication **requires much more work** for the company implementing it**. The Web services endpoint configured for the org must be developed, hosted, exposed on the Internet, and integrated with the company's identity store.

More detailed flow and code example on [delegated](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_delauthentication.htm&language=en_US)

[image]

More detailed flow on [SSO width SAML](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_SAML_on_Force.com)

[image]

Comment: I configured federated authentication. It is working fine through "Identity provider initiated login". How can I use "service provider initiated login"? What details I should give to sales force? my username and password?