# Direct login and federated login in salesforce

Tags: authentication, salesforce, saml-2.0, federated-identity

I configured salesforce for federated authentication. Great! I did?

It is working fine for "identity provider initiated login" (see [Federated authentication and Delegated authentication in salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369604/federated-authentication-and-delegated-authentication-in-salesforce/12370138#12370138)). I am using a federated id. But my issue that that user can login directly to salesforce using his username and password? How can I disable it?

The "service provider initiated login" says it will come to identity provider. It is not going to identity provider when I try to login using salesforce login page?

Comment: You should accept the answer in your previous question if it has helped you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369604/federated-authentication-and-delegated-authentication-in-salesforce/12370138#12370138)

Comment: @MartinBorthiry that helped me. But I need more clarification. But I feared that if I accept that nobody will try to answer that question. Anyway, I accepted your answer :)